# How to download all the files from a given format in a given URL related to a file server using command line

Tags: command-line, download

Suppose there is some URL: example.com/folder1. This URL, when accessed using browsers like Chrome and Firefox, is not a website as we're habituated, but a page containing files to download (I'd say a file server in HTTP, I know almost nothing about computer networks). Now, suppose that there are thousands of files from different formats, some are PNGs, others JPGs, others MP4, others TXT and others.

Say, I want to download all the PNG images there. I could use `wget example.com/folder1/name-of-image-1.png ; wget example.com/folder1/name-of-image-2.png ; [...] wget example.com/folder1/name-of-image-n.png`, but this is a long work, as the image names don't follow a pattern, and it would be very interesting to automate the things. I look for a command like `wget --download-all-from-format=png example.com/folder1`. This option, --download-all-from-format=png, doesn't exist, but I have came up with it to show you the idea. The solution may be in wget, curl or other command line program.

Searching in the internet, I have got some commands: `wget -nd -r -l 2 -accept-regex '.png' example.com/folder1` and `wget -nd -r -l 2 -A.png example.com/folder1`, but they haven't worked for me. Weird files are being downloaded, as this image shows:
[image]

My guess is that both commands I have seen maybe are useful for downloading a website content, however, in my case, the desired URL is not a website as we understand, but a file server on the internet (when I type the URL in my browser, I have a list similar to the list we get when the type, say, file:///home/user), that's the reason I haven't been successful. This server seems to be HTTP, not FTP.

Thank you.

Sincerely,

[UPDATE]
I have found a solution. It was not what I was expecting, but it works. I can download example.com/folder1 using wget without extra options, then I filter the downloaded file, getting all the images paths. Then I make a shell script ordering the computer to download individually each path I got, I can use a for loop in the list of all images paths.